# Converting String to KeyCode in Unity/C#, KeyCode isn't an enumType

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm attempting to create customizable controls for my Unity game, and to do this I've put several KeyCode names into strings for storage, however I can't seem to figure out how to turn them back into KeyCodes.

I did some looking and it seemed like, assuming `KeyString` says something like `"UpArrow"`, `Enum.TryParse(KeyCode, KeyString)` would work, however because `KeyCode` isn't an `enumType`, it's just a `Type`, this of course gives me the `'KeyCode' is a type, which is not valid in the given context` error in Unity.

Comment: Both the Unity docs and an old copy of the [source code](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference/blob/master/Runtime/Export/Input/Keycode.cs) show that its an enum. As you're not using the generic Tryparse method, the first argument to TryParse should be the reflection type, not just the type name. That is to say it should be `typeof(Keycode)`. You're also missing the out parameter.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.tryparse?view=net-6.0#system-enum-tryparse(system-type-system-string-system-object@)

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.tryparse?view=net-6.0#system-enum-tryparse-1(system-string-0@)